# I created an array of TImage but they aren't visible

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, visible, timage

I'm using Delphi and I created an array of ten elements of type `TImage` whit this name and structure:

```
Form3.images[1..max] of TImage.
```

I tried to initialize it in this way:

```
for x := 1 to max do
begin
  images[x] := TImage.Create(Form3);
  images[x].AutoSize := True;
  images[x].Name := 'image' + IntToStr(x);
  images[x].Visible := true;
  images[x].Parent := Form3;
end;
```

After that I tried to put the content of another variable (called Form3.a1:TImage) to every element of the array.

I tried to do this with these instructions:

```
for i := 1 to max do
begin
  Form3.Images[i]:=Form3.a1;             // ( Form3.a1: TImage) <- this is visible
end;
```

(I don't know if using the instructions before, is the right thing to do)
After that I changed positions of array's images:

```
//Form3.square:TShape

x := Form3.square.Left;
y := Form3.square.Top;
Form3.Images[1].Top := y + 70;
Form3.Images[1].Left := x + 60;
...
Form3.Images[1].Top := y + 10;
Form3.Images[1].Left := x + 50;
```

I set different positions for each image of the array but when I run the program, images of the array aren't visible. I also tried to set Form3.square.visible=false but nothing changes.

This is what I want:

- have the same contents between variable `a1` and variables of the array `images`, changing only positions
- make array's images visible (I tried `images[x].Visible := true;` but it doesn't work).

please i need help, I can give other details.
Thank you.

Comment: And what is the `Form3.Lista` if not an image list ?

Answer (score 3):

You forget to set the control's position; `Left` and `Top`. This is preferrably done by calling `SetBounds`. Also the dimensions are not specified , but that is taken care of by the `AutoSize` property (it wouldn't need it for becoming visible though).

Comment: Oh thank you! And sorry because I Forgot to say that I Set positions! Positions of images are the same of another object (that's a shape). I tried to put shape.visible=false to see if images were under it, but I couldn't see the images... pls heeeeeelp :(

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have set the position of the images in the `images` array (as you state in the comment on te [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484855/757830)), then the first code should work normally.

Check the following though:

- Are the `Width` and `Height` properties of the ImageList `Form3.Lista` set? Note that when you change them, the ImageList is cleared.
- Ensure that you are looking at the same `TForm3` instance as where the `Form3` variable points to. (You should not use that global form variable anyway!)

Now, about the second piece of code wherein you copy images from one to another:

- Is `a1` a (local) declared variable as you wrote halfway the question? Then `Form3.a1` (which is a private field of `TForm3`) and `a1` (the variable) are not the same!
- Note that you are copying from `Form3.a1` to `Images[i]`. Shouldn't that maybe the other way around?
- If this indeed is what you want: Is `Form3.a1` by any chance empty?

There are 2 more possibilities I can think of, but both would result in an exception, so I imagine these are not the case:

- ImageList `Form3.Lista` holds no or not enough images,
- Image `Form3.a1` holds no bitmap, but a gif, jpeg or other graphic type.

Comment: but there are some problems: I didn't use an ImageList;    The variable is only one and it's Form3.a1 . It has got a picture inside (a bitmap as I said). But, must I create an ImageList if I already have an images' array?

Comment: I assumed `Form3.Lista` is a `TImageList`, because you invoke `GetBitmap` on it. What type is `Form3.Lista` then?

Comment: It is a TimageList that I created, but I didn't do anything on it. Only that thing that you read. Couldn't we solve the problem without using a list? Is it necessary if I have an array of images? I don't think and I hope so. Because I don't know how to use an imageList